# How to keep dense particles at the center of emitter in blender 2.8?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make my emitter space look dense with the particles while emitting the particles. I'd done a setting which gave me the desired result but it was a hidden trial, now i'm trying to search it out for 4 days but not getting the setting exactly. I have added two pictures showing differences at center 
Please try to help me if anyone could.   Thanks.

High density particles at center.
[image]

Low density particles at center or no my emiter
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I actually understand what you're asking but: you can have two particle systems. One with a big particle lifetime, the other with a shorter one, and lesser emission speed.

Comment: a picture of what you have so far and the settings would make it easier to see where you need help.

Comment: Thank you @Kiskit and for acknowledging my ques. i'm trying to make it more clear by adding some of pictures.

Answer (score 0):

So as stated in a comment, you can have two particle systems.

One (in green here) is the "outer" system. The other one (in red) the "inner" system.

By giving different lifetimes and initial velocities to your systems, you can probably approach your desired result.

[image]

Green is long lived with high velocity

[image]

Red/inner is short lived and with low velocity

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much, this could be work as second way to make it. @Kiskit

Answer (score -1):

Yes i got the final way to it by turn one one setting in particle mode, all i want to make it more glowing at the center by using single particle system.[![Dead tab[![Dead tab disable result.

[image]

[image]

Should be enabled

[image]

Comment: If anything, try "Unborn". It should render particles before they are born, which is what happens if they're emitted from the center. "Dead" renders particles once they're dead, so if they originate from the center, they will accumulate at the periphery.
In any case, this is not the purpose of that option, but in the end, only the result counts.